# getJSON and return the value string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i would like to get string with **getJSON** function from my JSON document. I tried to return the value by everytime it return undefined. This is my code below. Thank you for your help.

```
 function getValues() {
       $.getJSON("layout.php",function(result){
         return result;    // this should be the return value
       });
 }


 var jsonString = getValues();
 alert(jsonString);
```

This is my layout.php document with JSON string

```
{"bigfield0":{"field0":{"collapse":"false"},"field1":{"collapse":"true"}},"bigfield1":{"field2":{"collapse":"false"}}}
```

Comment: Look up the term "asynchronous"...

Comment: -1 'getJSON and return the value string' = over 900 rsults

Answer (score 0):

The $.getJSON is using a callback and does not return the value. It's a asynchronius function.
You can watch the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Try to use this. That should return some data for you:

```
 function getValues() {
       $.getJSON("layout.php",function(result){
         alert(result);    // this should be the return value
       });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that `getJSON` is an async method, so it does work and the rest of your code keeps running. At the time where you try to use the results, the `getJSON` is still in progress. The solution: **callbacks**

```
function getValues(callback) {
   $.getJSON("layout.php",function(result){
     callback(result);    // this should be the return value
   });
}
```

And call this:

```
getValues(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in getJSON is an asynchronous call back function that cannot return a value.
Also to print JSON object as a string, you need to serialize that object into string.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
```

Your overall code should be like this:

```
//Code before the GET.

$.getJSON("layout.php",function(result){
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result) //asuming result is a JSON object.
    // the remaining of your script.
});
```